# Hayes Sole Disk Brakes, adjusters stiff/seized?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, hayes

Second hand bike, my first time encountering Hayes Sole brake calipers. My brakes front and back have gone a bit weak so I wanted to tighten them up a bit. Each side of caliper has an allen key section that pushes in each brake pad. When you pull the brakes(hydraulic) one pad moves in and the other is static. https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hayes-hydraulic-brake-service

Front brakes are okay, I could screw in the static side a bit while the moving side is already all the way in(it does screw out ok), brake pads look like they have a bit more life left. Braking feels ok now but maybe not super strong. :-7

Back brakes both sides are stuck, I can neither screw them in nor out. I have cleaned a bit will leave oil/WD40 (***WARNING! you should lubricate using DOT brake fluid, especially do not get oil/WD40 anywhere near or on piston seals or brake pads or brake disc***) soak in and start using more force tomorrow but I was wondering is this a problem someone else has encountered, does anyone have any experience and advice with regards to these brakes?

Thanks.

Comment: "will leave oil soak in" -- Are you putting *oil* on the piston seals???  This will cause the seals to swell and jam the pistons!  Some bike disk brakes use oil, but the Hayes (see your link) uses DOT brake fluid -- basically an alcohol/glycerin mix.  This type of fluid is used in large part because it doesn't attack rubber parts like regular mineral oil does.

Comment: Ah, yes I put on oil and also WD40, oh dear, one side isn't a piston seal so I guess oil would be ok there. Cause the seals to swell ? :( So best to try lubricate with dot brake fluid. Would WD40 also be bad?

Comment: Yes, WD40 would be bad.  (And note that it is very important to keep any sort of lubricant off the discs and pads.)

Comment: Yes, it's dodgy spraying WD40 near brake discs & pads, I know, I was careful! Anyway, update: I had wiped off oil/WD40 but no DOT brake fluid to hand so I left it. The next morning I tried again and both sides shifted, so I think the WD40 did help! I guess it would be ok on the non-piston side as long as you are careful. But it could lead to trouble on the piston side.