# Brake pads don’t fit into the calipers

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-pads

This is my first time replacing the brake pads of hydraulic brakes. 
I removed the old ones and the model was Shimano B01S Resin, so I bought the same ones.
However, when I have replaced them. They don’t fit into the calipers... well they fit but there is no space for the disc between the pads.
I have drained the brakes completely and nothing...
Does anyone has an idea about that?

Thanks in advance. I have attached some pics about the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you push the pistons back into the caliper before putting in the new brake pads?  You didn't need to drain the fluid.

Comment: Ok, problem solve. As  @Criggie commented there is no need to drain the fluid and just needed to push back the pistons. Thank you for the advise.

Comment: Make sure you properly re-fill the fluid according to the manufacturers specified procedure.

Comment: Do not push the levers when there is no disc in the calipers. Even when traveling, put some inserts (e.g. old bent credit card) into the calipers to protect them.

Comment: @FélixdelPradoHurtado would you mind doing a write-up of what you did ?  Could be a good canonical answer.   SE permits self-answering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change my disc brake pads?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-do-i-change-my-disc-brake-pads)

Answer (score 2):

I got to fix it just pushing back the pistons with a plastic card. Once they are in their position there was space enough like to set the wheel and the disc brake in it.